# Proof that $a+b+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}\geq\frac{5}{2}$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Kazakstan 2012

Suppose that $a, b \in\mathbb{R}$, and $a,b>0$. If $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=2$

prove that $a+b+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}\geq\frac{5}{2}.$

My idea :

$a+b+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}$ can be written as $ab(\frac{a+b}{ab}+\frac{1-\sqrt{ab}}{1-ab})=2ab+\frac{1-\sqrt{ab}}{ab-a^2b^2}$, but where  can I use the fact that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=2?$

Comment: Note: This question was [posted again an hour later](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961924/let-a-and-b-be-two-real-positive-numbers-show-that-ab-frac11-sqrta), which makes me suspect it's from a live-ish source.

Comment: kazakstan??????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have: $4(ab)^2 = (a+b)^2 \ge 4ab \implies ab \ge 1\implies LHS \ge 2\sqrt{ab} + \dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}= f(t), t = \sqrt{ab} \ge 1\implies f'(t) = 2 - \dfrac{1}{(1+t)^2}> 0\implies f(t) \ge f(1) = 2+\dfrac{1}{2} = \dfrac{5}{2} \implies LHS \ge \dfrac{5}{2} = RHS $. Equality occurs when $a = b = 1$.

Comment: can you gift me more information about your answer method?, you know i just newbie at inequality, this material is not discussed much in my class

Comment: @AllifQalbiy: I have a book that discusses various ways to use the AM-GM inequality and I just studied those methods and apply them to the problems. I also combine them with other inequalities. But you have to be "strong" with fractions and exponents.

Comment: i think you can gift me a link, or more example or something that make me more understand

Comment: @AllifQalbiy: I recommend you to get in touch with user Michael Rozenberg here at MSE. He is the expert in inequalities. Just look him up and contact him. Maybe he knows some books and he can help you further.

Comment: thanks @The73SuperBug

Comment: Why $f'(t)$ must be greather than $0$ ?

Comment: @The73SuperBug Why $f'(t)$ must be greather than $0$ implies $f(t) \ge f(1)$ ?

Comment: @AllifQalbiy There are tons of resources on AoPS (Art of Problem Solving) from other users who know inequalities.

Comment: Apart from the differentiation, another approach is to show that $ 2t + 1/(1+t) - 2.5 \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow 2(t-1)(t+3/4) / (t+1) \geq 0 $, and so it holds for $ t \geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

From the hypothesis: $a+b=2ab$
So the claim can be written as: $2ab+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}\geqslant 2.5$
Now to make everything based on $ab$, we analyze the hypothesis:
For which real values $x$, there exist $a,b$ such that $ab=x , \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=2$?
For solving this put $a$ as our variable. We want to find $a$ such that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{a}{x}=2$ or equivalently: $2ax=x+a^2$ now if we see this as a polynomial, $a$ exists iff $4x^2-4x\geqslant 0$ which happens iff $x\geqslant 1$ or $0\geqslant x$.

So now we can state the problem as follows:
For any real number $x$ such that $x$ isn't between $0$ and $1$, prove that $2x+\frac{1}{1+\sqrt x }\geqslant 2.5$

Now note that $x$ can't be negative because of the square root and this function is increasing for $x\geqslant 1$ so the minimum value is taken on $x=1$ which completes the proof.

Comment: Another way to complete the last paragraph is to show that $ 2x + 1/( 1 + \sqrt{x}) - 2.5 > 0 $ can be factored to $ ( \sqrt{x} - 1 ) ( \sqrt{x} + 1/2 ) ( \sqrt{x} + 3/2 ) / ( \sqrt{x} + 1 ) > 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not involve derivatives.

By AM-GM, we have that $a+b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}$. Hence it suffices for us to prove that $2\sqrt{ab}+\dfrac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}} \geq \dfrac{5}{2}.$

From the given condition, $\dfrac{1}{a} + \dfrac{1}{b} =2 \Rightarrow a+b=2ab \Rightarrow 2ab \geq 2\sqrt{ab} \Rightarrow \sqrt{ab} \geq 1$. Hence, letting $x=\sqrt{ab}, x \geq 1$, we have to prove that:

\begin{align}
& 2x+\dfrac{1}{1+x} \geq \dfrac{5}{2} \\
& \iff \dfrac{2x(1+x)+1}{1+x} \geq \dfrac{5}{2} \\
& \iff \dfrac{2x^2+2x+1}{1+x} \geq \dfrac{5}{2} \\
& \iff 2(2x^2+2x+1) \geq 5+5x \\
& \iff 4x^2-x \geq  3 \\
& \iff x(4x-1) \geq 3 \\
\end{align}
But the last inequality is obvious since $x \geq 1$ and $4x-1 \geq 4-1=3$; hence we are done.