# Let $a$ and $b$ be two real positive numbers. Show that $a+b+\frac{1}{1+ \sqrt{ab}} \ge \frac{5}{2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Edit:**

Let $a$ and $b$ be two real positive numbers. If $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = 2$, show that

$a+b+\frac{1}{1+ \sqrt{ab}} \ge \frac{5}{2}$.

How to factorize the term $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{ab}}$ out, to get ineq by the AM-GM ineq?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3961882/proof-that-ab-frac11-sqrtab-geq-frac52/3961898#3961898

Comment: Great. Thanks! ${}{}$

Comment: @TobyMak why $f'(t)$ must be greater than $0$ ?

Comment: I recommend you ask a separate question for this.

Comment: @user795084 If you solve for $f'(t) = 0$, note that $t ≥ 1$ so it is true for all $t$ in that domain.

Comment: I mean, why it can implies $f(t) \ge f(1)$ ? What is the correlation?

Comment: I'm not answering your question in the comments. If you want an answer, please post a new question and make your question clear.